# "Китовый" объектив

Tags: фонетика

Читаю литературу по фотографии и уперлась в слово "китовый" (объектив). Сразу хотелось сделать ударение "китОвый" по аналогии с китовым усом или китовым жиром. Но тут речь не о китах, а об английском слове kit, то есть, комплект (объектив идет в комплекте с фотоаппаратом). И как в таком случае ставить ударение? Распространяется ли на это слово то же правило, что и на русское слово "кит", или все-таки надо говорить "кИтовый"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы скорее сказал, что кИтовый, чем китОвый (к китам как к животным отношения ведь не имеет).

Answer (score 0):

В Вики дается ударение "кИтовый"

Comment: В следующий раз старайтесь давать более развернутые ответы.